# How to include a new order status in between pending and processing in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, order-status

I want to include a new order status in between pending and processing.  i.e., after placing an order the status is pending and after this, I want to change to [New order status] and then processing status, when we click on a ship action, it changes. Suggest me, how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For this You need to create new status and assign it to State 
go to admin panel Stores > Settings > Order Status
create  YOUR NEW STATUS
after that go to "Assign Status to State", here select YOUR NEW STATUS
and Set Order State "Pending" now save it .

so now when you will create new order then order status will be pending . after that you can view and changed it YOUR NEW STATUS